# Animating the addition of a string to a ListBox in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, animation, listbox, firemonkey, tlistbox

The following code nicely animates adding a new string to the end of a ListBox

```
procedure TForm6.AddItem(s: string);
var
  l : TListBoxItem;
  OldHeight : Single;
begin
  l := TListBoxItem.Create(Self);
  l.Text := s;
  OldHeight := l.Height;
  l.Height := 0;
  l.Parent := ListBox1;
  l.Opacity := 0;
  l.AnimateFloat('height', OldHeight, 0.5);
  l.AnimateFloat('Opacity', 1, 0.5);
end;
```

The item expands and fades in.  However I want to be able to add the string into an arbitrary location in the ListBox - actually at the current ItemIndex.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work around the fact that `ListBox1.InsertObject` and `ListBox1.Items.Insert` don't work you can do the following

```
procedure TForm1.AddItem(s: string);
var
  l : TListBoxItem;
  OldHeight : Single;
  I: Integer;
  index : integer;
begin
  l := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
  l.Text := s;
  OldHeight := l.Height;
  l.Height := 0;
  l.Opacity := 0;
  l.Index := 0;
  l.Parent := ListBox1;

  Index := Max(0, ListBox1.ItemIndex);
  for I := ListBox1.Count - 1 downto Index + 1 do
  begin
    ListBox1.Exchange(ListBox1.ItemByIndex(i), ListBox1.ItemByIndex(i-1));
  end;
  ListBox1.ItemIndex := Index;
  l.AnimateFloat('height', OldHeight, 0.5);
  l.AnimateFloat('Opacity', 1, 0.5);
end;
```

but is a bit ridiculous.  It (eventually) adds the string in position 0 if there is no item selected, otherwise adds it before the selected item.  This solution reminds me too much of [Bubble Sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnK5ueUgc88).  You will need to add the math unit to your uses clause for the max function to work.

This does indeed seem to be a bug in FireMonkey (check Quality Central [#102122](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=102122)), However I suspect a future FireMonkey update will fix this.  If anyone can see a better way of doing this....

I've also [made a movie](http://learndelphi.tv/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=109%3amovie-66-animating-adding-a-tlistboxitem&catid=17%3amovie&Itemid=27) about this for those who are interested, which illustrates things more clearly.

Comment: It works fine. Shuffling the list is pretty quick unless you have a very large list.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, but it does nothing:

```
l := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox1);
ListBox1.InsertObject(Max(ListBox1.ItemIndex, 0), l);
```

If I then call the following, I get an access violation:

```
ListBox1.Realign;
```

In fact, even this gives me an AV:

```
ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, 'hello');
ListBox1.Realign;
```

But this adds one, of course:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add('hello');
```

A bug perhaps?

Comment: Yup, I'm getting the same result - I agree - likely a bug

Comment: As stated above, Listbox.items.Insert is currently broken. Maybe fix in update 4?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
l.Parent := ListBox1;
```

use

```
ListBox1.InsertObject(Index, l);
```

where Index is the insertion position.

(Untested but from reading the sources it should work).

Comment: ListBox1.InsertObject(0, l) doesn't work and gives an access violation, although if I remove the code related to the animation, the listbox1.count increases but nothing visibly changes.  ListBox1.AddObject(l) works fine however (although gives the same result as my original code).